# Exclude one row from join result based on another row

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have two tables like this.

```
select * from TABLE1

C1  C2
1   1
```

```
select * from TABLE2

C2  C4  enabled
1       true
1   2   false
2   2   true
```

Now after a full outer join results looks like below

```
select * from TABLE1 t1 full outer join TABLE2 t2 on t1.C2 = t2.C2;

C1  C2  C4     enabled
1   1          true
1   1   2      false
2   2          true
```

Now if I want to exclude row 2 & row 3 in result because enabled = `false` for row 2 and column t2.C4 value needs to be matched to t1.C2 value so row 3 is also removed as a result.
I can remove row 2 with a where condition on enabled column but how can I remove row 3 based on row 2 ?

Expected result with final join query removing enabled=false both direct and implied rows.

```
C1  C2  C4     enabled

1   1          true
```

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result

Comment: These seem like two independent things.  Do they somehow interfere with each other?  If not, then why are you asking them together, especially since you already seem to know the answer to one of them.  If they do interfere, please highlight how.

Comment: I am trying to get a single query to filter both of the rows above when one row references other post the join. I can do it using a NOT exists query on table TABLE1  but looking for a better solution.

Comment: Can you share your solution with `NOT exists`? Why do you dislike it?

Comment: @SimonPerepelitsa I am hitting the table twice, once before join and once after so I am trying to see if I can improve on that. Something like. "select * from TABLE1 t1 full outer join TABLE2 t2 on t1.C2 = t2.C2 where t2.enabled = false not exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t2.C4 != t1.C2 and t2.enabled = false )"